# use scrapy ltem_loader add_css extract data, but the value is None, how do i set default value

Tags: python, scrapy

when I use scrapy item_loader to fill item, the selector extract data is None. Then, I use mysql to save data, but it gives me a mistake: key Error, the reason is this instance no this key. after i researched, there is no solution. Could you help me? Thank you very much!

```
        real_time_hot_loader = WeiBoRealTimeHotLoader(item=WeiBORealTimeHotItem(),selector=real_time_hot_node)
        real_time_hot_loader.add_css('search_rank', 'tr[action-type*="hover"] td.td_01 span em::text')
        real_time_hot_loader.add_css('star_name', 'td.td_02 p.star_name a::text')
        real_time_hot_loader.add_css('star_url', 'td.td_02 p.star_name a::attr(href)')
        real_time_hot_loader.add_css('star_num', 'td.td_03 p.star_num span::text')
        real_time_hot_loader.add_css('hot_txt','td.td_02 p.star_name i.icon_txt::text')
        real_time_hot_loader.add_value('update_time', time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()))
        real_time_hot_loader.add_value('id', real_time_hot_date_time_id)
        real_time_hot_item = real_time_hot_loader.load_item()
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default scrapy's ItemLoader discards any fields that are `None`

To fix this you need to make sure the loader fallsback to some other value like empty string: `""`

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose

def or_empty_string(value):
    return value or ''

class MyLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = Compose(or_empty_string)
```

Now you can see this in action:

```
>>> l = MyLoader()
>>> l.add_value('foo', None)
>>> l.load_item()
{}
>>> l.add_value('foo', '')
>>> l.load_item()
{'foo': ['']}
```

Comment: @何明扬 cool, if the issue was solved click the little checkmark on the left of the post to mark it solved :)